# jquery ajax is not working

Tags: ajax, jquery

i have two files trying to use ajax

here is code of test.php file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var email = $('#email').val();
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"test1.php", 
                success:function(){
                    alert('');
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Email:<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is code of test1.php file

```
<?php 
    echo "hi";
    exit;
?>
```

it is not working i am not able to get alert in sucess function

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you execute this page using `http://` only right?

Comment: Try giving a `return false` in the end of the `click` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the submit button type to just a button. Otherwise, you are submitting the form before the ajax is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a `return false` in the end of the `click` function.

```
var email = $('#email').val();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"",
            success:function(){
                alert('');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});​
```

This might work!

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd use the submit event on the form because if you bind the click event on the submit button, the submit event still gets triggered.

see the example here

http://api.jquery.com/submit/